# Ionic Authentication + PHP response token. Safe enough?

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, ionic-framework

I'm making an App based on Ionic Framework which have authentications.

There is my way:

1. Send `Username` and `Password` to the server backend (PHP).
2. (if credential matches) Server response a `token`. (`token` is a random string, 24 digits)
3. Save the `token`. Append to the header on every request.
4. If `token` is valid, response what they request as a logged in user.

Is my solution above safe enough?

My question is:

1. At Step 2., If someone changes the key belongs to others, can they operate anything pretending like account owner?
2. It's save to keep the key at users' mobile phone?

Is that something else I can do to improve the security? Or just my doubts?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is this trying to solve (is this a question about CSRF)? How does it differ from the session provided by PHP (again, is this about CSRF or another problem, such as a lack-of-session support)? [I'm not sure if ionic supports cookies; but that 'token' is effectively what a session cookie is. And yes, *anyone with that 'secret' can pretend to be the user*, which is why it is important to keep secrets secret!]

Comment: How is this any different than any standard cookie-based login system? you fill out the form, session ID is sent back and forth as a cookie, and you store the login status in the cookie.

Comment: Thank you two. And you mean there's no difference between cookie-based login and my way?

And what else I can do to have a security improvement at PHP backend side?